# Select different combinations for same table msSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which has 2 fields `OS_ID` and `OZ_ID`. I want to select combinations of `OS_ID` for different `OZ_ID`. What would be the query for that?

#### Input

```
OS_ID   OZ_ID        
----    ----
1       1
2       1
3       2
4       2
5       2
6       2
7       3
8       3
9       3
```

#### Output

combination row

```
1,3,7
1,3,8
1,3,9
1,4,7
1,4,8
1,4,9
1,5,7
1,5,8
1,5,9
1,6,7
1,6,8
1,6,9
2,4,7
2,4,8
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want Cross Joins:

```
SELECT t1.OS_ID, t2.OS_ID, t3.OS_ID 
FROM tab AS t1
CROSS JOIN tab AS t2
CROSS JOIN tab AS t3 
WHERE t1.OZ_ID = 1 
  AND t2.OZ_ID = 2 
  AND t3.OZ_ID = 3
```